# Push file to sql server stored proc to save in Blob, then retrieve said file

Tags: c#, sql-server, blob, varbinary

I have found a lot of references to how to save a file to a blob field (VARBINARY), but they all seem to require that the sql server have access to the file on the file system.  Our web server resides on a different machine and unfortunately there's not a shared file location that I can use for my purposes.

I'd like to push the file up from my web app (C# code) as a parameter to a stored proc: @FileStream   VARBINARY(MAX) and then save it that way.  Is this possible to do?

likewise, I'd like to be able to fetch the file from the sql server and save it to the web server's file system later.

Any help (code samples) would be greatly appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file contents are small enough to keep in memory, a simple parameter with a `byte[]` will work just fine:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileStream", 
    SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1) { Value = someBytes });
```

When reading, again if it's small enough to not worry about streaming, you can do:

```
byte[] contents = (byte[])rdr[rdr.GetOrdinal("FileStream")];
```

Comment: thx Joe, this looks exactly like what I'm looking for.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I tweaked it just a bit, but this was perfect.  Thanks much.

Comment: This isn't streaming, so if you deal with large files you will run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do what you say, however it won't be "streaming." For example, if you intend to send the file from SQL -> web server -> browser, it won't start sending it to the browser until the entire file is transferred from SQL -> web server. This is where the SQL Server FILESTREAM feature (which I think is what you are referring to) comes in as it would all bi-directional streaming.